# Build Xamarin app in Visual Studio 2022 - requires TLS 1.2

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, xamarin

We have a Xamarin app that has been working for years. It communicates with a WebService using https and has its SSL/TLS implementation set to Native TLS 1.2+. Up to this week we had been building the app in Visual Studio 2017. So far no problems.

This week we upgraded to Visual Studio 2022. We rebuilt the app without changing anything in the code and using the Visual Studio debugger ran it on our test device. Immediately we began to get the error *'ConnectFailure (TLS Support not available.)'* when we tried to connect to the webService.

I checked the server on which the webService is hosted and it appears to have TLS 1.2 enabled and anyway it worked ok last week when the 2017 built app had the exact same SSL/TLS setting.

What is different about Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: Where is the relevant code that produces the exception?  Is this Android or iOS?  Which version?  Are you using the same version of the tools and OS as you were using previously in VS2017?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry I should have said this is an Android 8.1 app. Nothing was changed in the switch to VS2022. I installed VS2022, opened the existing solution and tried (a) running through the debugger and (b) building the apk and installing on the device. 

An example of the code that fails:

`       public long GetServerTicks(string strDID)
        {
            var webService = DependencyService.Get<VT_MobileSalesApp.Interfaces.IVT_TrafficWebService>();
            return webService.GetVerifyNowServerTicks(strDID);

        }`

but the error could happen on any of the webService calls

Comment: I have tried the app in VS2019 also today and it behaves just like VS2022